# Finding the Best Fitting Plane Given a Set of 3D Points

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose that we have $n$ points in 3D.

I want to find a plane $ax + by + cz + d$ such that sum of all the orthogonal distances to the plane is minimum.

I read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Linear_least_squares) article. However, I need an algorithmic solution.

So far, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400338/3403689) answer from SO was the simplest one. However, this solution projects the points onto $z=0$ plane all the time.

Could you help me to write the algorithm? I'll code it in Java.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "However, I need an algorithmic solution."  Least squares *is* an algorithmic solution.  It *does* have the problem that it doesn't solve your problem -- it solves a related optimization problem, but not your problem -- but it's certainly an algorithmic solution, as there are standard algorithms to compute the least squares fit plane.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the problem that PCA (principal component analysis) solves.  So, use PCA -- that provides an algorithmic solution to this problem.  See [this explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2700/2921) over at Statistics.SE for an explanation of why PCA solves this problem.

[Least squares fitting is almost a solution to this problem, except that it doesn't minimize the orthogonal distance -- it minimizes the distance along the $y$ axis, or any single axis you might pick.]

---

If for some reason you didn't want to use PCA, you could frame this as a mathematical optimization problem (the objective function is the total orthogonal distance) and then use any standard optimization technique -- e.g., gradient descent -- to find an approximate optimum.